# Why do semiconductors remain neutral outside the depletion region?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Why there is a sharp cut off of the charged region outside the depletion region, like on [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pn-junction-equilibrium-graphs.png)?

For example why don't electrons on the conduction band in the n-type side rush towards the positively charged area making the whole piece positively charged somewhat, not just at the area near the depletion region?

The source of the confusion is that I know if you charge up a regular conductors the internal currents will uniformly distribute the charge along the whole piece, while insulators are only locally charged up, since they cannot carry current. 
Semiconductors here seem to act like insulators, but diodes do carry current when used. How?

Comment: Because the depletion region has done its job and equilibrated the Fermi energy between regions of different doping. If the Fermi levels are equilibrated then there is no driving force for net carrier redistribution.

Comment: @JonCuster the question is not about why does the charge transfer between the pieces stop. The question is. when the pieces are in equilibrium why don't the remaining charge carriers distribute themselves uniformly in each half. Why there aren't any electric field? The + ions are a little closer than the - ions so there should be a little net force from + charges. Or let's see another example: you ground the negative end of a 9V battery and connect the other into piece of semiconductor, will the whole piece charge up to 9V or it only does that right next to the battery only like an insulator?

Comment: "why don't the remaining charge carriers distribute themselves uniformly in each half" The remain charge carriers are ions that are lock u

Answer (score 0):

I think the graphic you're looking at is a simplification.  The positive and negative ends of the charge regions are probably a bit more trapezoidal (sloped) 
than the sharp discontinuities represented there for simplicity.  After all, the color representation above is a bit fuzzy at the edges.

Answer (score 0):

The negative charges in the n type side are repelled by the negative ions in the p type region and positive charges in the p type side are repelled by the positive ions in the n type region in the equilibrium condition of diode. That's why charges are unable to travel across the pn junction. I hope you know about the n type and p type materials.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the depletion region approximation. Which by the way is actually pretty good, especially when the junction is revered biased.
When it is forward biased, or one side is highly doped sometimes it is not as good and it would be better to work out the solution numerically. Then you could find that the edges are not sharp.

Part of the reason the edges are sharp when you make the approximation is that the carrier concentrations are pretty large and the doping is supposed to be uniform. Then assumption is that there are no  free carriers since they get swept out by the electric field.

I think the other thing to consider in answering your question is that you end up balancing drift and diffusion currents to maintain charge neutrality.

Answer (score 0):

From your response to @JonCuster:

> The question is. when the pieces are in equilibrium why don't the remaining charge carriers distribute themselves uniformly in each half.

The remaining charge carriers within the depletion region are not electrons but semiconductor ions (both positive and negative) locked into their positions within the crystal so they can't move. If the lattice ions could move, then they would redistribute themselves to eliminate or minimize the electric field across the junction.